# what to do if i can not retireve value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT a.*,
       (select count(*) from f4s56_itcs_fields c where c.fid=a.id) nbfields,
       (select b.username from f4s56_users b where a.created_by = b.id) username 
FROM f4s56_itcs_forms a 
where a.created_by=326 
   or a.group in(2,3,9)
```

here, "a.group" could be 2 or 3 or 4 or 2,3,4,5,6 etc.
Means, group may be single value or multiple valued. when it is multiple valued, data is not being retrieved. how to fix that?

Comment: My dear first explain your table structure, then what you want, then you have tried and then your problem. Be tech.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? I'm not sure I understand what you expect to find in which cases.

Comment: Would a column containing 2,3,4,5,6 match in(2,3,9)? Or would it compare the multivalue as a whole?

Comment: The wise thing would be changing your DB structure and normalizing your data.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the `f4s56_itcs_forms.group` column (or `a.group` aliased), is a string-type column that can contain single or multiple values:

```
a.group
-------
1
2
4
2,5
2,3,5,7
```

If this is correct, you won't be able to do a direct comparison checking for a "list of values" that are contained "in the list of values in `a.group`". You can, however, do individual-value checks using MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) using `a.group` as the set you're looking at.

For instance, let's say you want to find all records that have the value `2` in `a.group`:

```
...
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(2, a.`group`) > 0
```

If you have multiple values you want to check for, you'll need to add each of them separately:

```
...
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(2, a.`group`) > 0
    AND FIND_IN_SET(3, a.`group`) > 0
    AND FIND_IN_SET(9, a.`group`) > 0
```

Comment: okay, thank you a lot, I am trying it in my code hope it helps... :)

Answer (score 0):

IM not sure if i understand your query but try this .

```
    SELECT a.*,b.username, count(*) from f4s56_itcs_forms a  
    INENR JOIN f4s56_users b
    on  a.created_by = b.id   
    INNER JOIN  f4s56_itcs_fields c
    on c.fid=a.id
    where a.created_by=326 or a.`group` in(2,3,9)
```

NOTE: that you have i think column called `group` so you should escape it by backticks like that

```
      `group`
```

If you are storing multiple values in one column then you can do this.

```
   where a.created_by=326 or FIND_IN_SET(2, a.`group`) > 0
                          or FIND_IN_SET(3, a.`group`) > 0
                          or FIND_IN_SET(9, a.`group`) > 0
```

Comment: I think OP was bigger problems. Looks like (s)he stores multiple values in a.group sometimes and then no result is returned.

Comment: sorry for not being able to clarify my problem.
Actually, I am retrieving values depending upon this query.
juergen d have told the right one. I am getting the values when a.group contains single value. when it is multiple, though a.group is 2,3,4 and the Query is 

SELECT a.*,b.username, count(*) from f4s56_itcs_fields c 
    INENR JOIN f4s56_users b
    on c.fid=a.id  
    INNER JOIN f4s56_itcs_forms a
    on a.created_by = b.id

i am unable to retrieve value.
    where a.created_by=326 or a.`group` in(2,3,9)

Comment: @arnas no not this i have updated my answer this one was having little msitake , try edited one now

Comment: @echo_Me If you use `LIKE '%2%'`, and a.group contained the values `12` or `20` - they would match too. You would have to use `(a.group = '2' or a.group like '2,%' or a.group like '%,2' or a.group like '%,2,%')` for every value.

Answer (score 0):

### Related to searching within comma separated values

> when it is multiple valued, data is not being retrieved.

**Based on newfurniturey's answer**, you can use find_in_set() to search through comma separated values.

**SQLFiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f514/1

Unfortunately you would need to convert:

- `in(2,3,9)` 
  **to**
- `FIND_IN_SET('2', a.'group') > 0 or FIND_IN_SET('3', a.'group') > 0 or FIND_IN_SET('9', a.'group') > 0`

Resulting in an SQL:

```
SELECT a.*,
           (select count(*) from f4s56_itcs_fields c where c.fid=a.id) nbfields,
           (select b.username from f4s56_users b where a.created_by = b.id) username 
    FROM f4s56_itcs_forms a 
    where a.created_by=326 
       or FIND_IN_SET('2', a.`group`) > 0
       or FIND_IN_SET('3', a.`group`) > 0
       or FIND_IN_SET('9', a.`group`) > 0;
```

### Related to data:

If the above is not the case, your issue may be related to data. I have created a test schema based on your query and results are returned.

**SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3763b/1**

```
create table f4s56_itcs_fields
(
  field_id int,
  field_name varchar(20),
  fid int
);

create table f4s56_users
(
  id int,
  username varchar(100)
);

create table f4s56_itcs_forms
(
   id int,
   created_by int, 
   `group` int
);


insert into f4s56_users values (326, 'user_326');
insert into f4s56_users values (327, 'user_327');

insert into f4s56_itcs_fields values (1,'name',1);
insert into f4s56_itcs_fields values (2,'last name',1);
insert into f4s56_itcs_fields values (3,'telephone',1);

insert into f4s56_itcs_forms values (1, 326, 2);
insert into f4s56_itcs_forms values (2, 326, 3);
insert into f4s56_itcs_forms values (2, 326, 9);
```